# PayPal REST API is not executing payments. Cannot change state of Payment object from 'created' to 'approved' or 'completed'

Tags: jakarta-ee, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using servlets to generate HTML pages that are designed to execute PayPal payments using the new REST api. I have not yet been able to generate a payment with a status of approved or created. I've tried variations on the PaymentWithPayPalServlet.java example from the github page, and I've included the closest variation below. I am most unclear about which object is supposed to receive the updated status of 'approved' or 'completed' and when.

Although I've included the full code below, here is a quick breakdown of my thinking. Perhaps someone can correct me where I go wrong...

I create a Payment object with all the appropriate attributes/properties set.

```
Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setIntent("sale");
payment.setPayer(payer);
payment.setTransactions(transactions);
payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);
Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);
```

Now, the createdPayment object has a status of "created". At the end of my code, I redirect the user to the payPal page where I assumed payPal would approve the payment before execution. Note, this is a deviation from the example file, but I do not understand why this doesn't work.

```
if (link.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url")) 
{
         req.setAttribute("redirectURL", link.getHref());
         resp.sendRedirect(link.getHref());
}
```

Since payPal cannot change the state of my local variable createdPayment through HTTP protocol, I expected the payPal page to redirect back to my returnURL page with a paymentID and possibly an authorization token appended to the URL. Using these two things, I expected to retrieve a payment object from the payPal server with some type of static function call, like:

```
String authToken=req.getParameter("token");
String paymentID=req.getParameter("paymentID");
Payment approvedPayment=Payment.getPaymentObject(authToken,paymentID);
```

However, the URL does not have any paymentID appended. Instead, there is a payerID. Further, all my attempts to retrieve a payment object from the payPal server with a status of 'approved' or 'completed' have failed. Basically, I tried variations on the following to no avail:

```
String authToken=req.getParameter("token");
String paymentID=req.getParameter("payerID");
Payment approvedPayment=Payment.get(authToken,payerID);
```

If anyone could tip me off to where my reasoning has gone wrong, that'd absolutely rock. Thanks! Here is the full code from my main servlet page. Note, the returnURL brings you back to the same page, where it finds a payerID included in the HTTP request from payPal and correctly enters the 'if' block of the main if-else statement, which generates some basic output that is entirely unhelpful. Also note that I have outsourced some basic functions calls, like retrieving the access tokens and contexts, to other classes, like the AccessToken class.

```
public class PaymentInfoServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   // private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
     //               .getLogger(PaymentWithPayPalServlet.class);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
            // ##Load Configuration
            // Load SDK configuration for
            // the resource. This intialization code can be
            // done as Init Servlet.
            InputStream is = PaymentInfoServlet2.class
                            .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");
            try {
                    PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
            } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
                  //  LOGGER.fatal(e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(req, resp);
    }

    // ##Create
    // Sample showing to create a Payment using PayPal
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
            // ###AccessToken
            // Retrieve the access token from
            // OAuthTokenCredential by passing in
            // ClientID and ClientSecret
            APIContext apiContext = null;
            String accessToken = null;
            try {
                AccessToken access=new AccessToken(PublicUtils.getUser(),PublicUtils.getPass(),req,resp);

                    accessToken = access.getToken();

                    // ### Api Context
                    // Pass in a `ApiContext` object to authenticate
                    // the call and to send a unique request id
                    // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
                    // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly.
                    apiContext = access.getContext();
                    // Use this variant if you want to pass in a request id
                    // that is meaningful in your application, ideally
                    // a order id.
                    /*
                     * String requestId = Long.toString(System.nanoTime(); APIContext
                     * apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken, requestId ));
                     */
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    req.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
            }
            if (req.getParameter("PayerID") != null) {
                    Payment payment = new Payment();
                    if (req.getParameter("guid") != null) {
                            payment.setId(map.get(req.getParameter("guid")));
                    }

                    PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution();
                    paymentExecution.setPayerId(req.getParameter("PayerID"));
                    try {
                            payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
                            req.setAttribute("response", Payment.getLastResponse());
                    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
                            req.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
                    out.println("This is the returnURL page.");
                    out.println("paymentID="+payment.getId());
                    out.println("pamentState="+payment.getState());
                    out.println("executedPayerID="+paymentExecution.getPayerId());
                   // out.println("executedTransaction: "+paymentExecution.getTransactions().get(0).toString());
            } else {

                    // ###Details
                    // Let's you specify details of a payment amount.
                    Details details = new Details();
                    details.setShipping("1");
                    details.setSubtotal("5");
                    details.setTax("1");

                    // ###Amount
                    // Let's you specify a payment amount.
                    Amount amount = new Amount();
                    amount.setCurrency("USD");
                    // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                    amount.setTotal("7");
                    amount.setDetails(details);

                    // ###Transaction
                    // A transaction defines the contract of a
                    // payment - what is the payment for and who
                    // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
                    // a `Payee` and `Amount` types
                    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                    transaction.setAmount(amount);
                    transaction
                                    .setDescription("This is the payment transaction description.");

                    // The Payment creation API requires a list of
                    // Transaction; add the created `Transaction`
                    // to a List
                    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
                    transactions.add(transaction);

                    // ###Payer
                    // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
                    // Payment Method
                    // as 'paypal'
                    Payer payer = new Payer();
                    payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal");

                    // ###Payment
                    // A Payment Resource; create one using
                    // the above types and intent as 'sale'
                    Payment payment = new Payment();
                    payment.setIntent("sale");
                    payment.setPayer(payer);
                    payment.setTransactions(transactions);

                    // ###Redirect URLs
                    RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
                    String guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
                    redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(req.getScheme() + "://"
                                    + req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort()
                                    + req.getContextPath() + "/CancelServlet?guid=" + guid);
                    redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(req.getScheme() + "://"
                                    + req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort()
                                    + req.getContextPath() + "/PaymentInfoServlet2?guid=" + guid);
                    payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

                    // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
                    // using a valid AccessToken
                    // The return object contains the status;
                    try {
                            Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);
                         //   LOGGER.info("Created payment with id = "
                           //                 + createdPayment.getId() + " and status = "
                             //               + createdPayment.getState());
                            // ###Payment Approval Url
                            Iterator<Links> links = createdPayment.getLinks().iterator();
                            while (links.hasNext()) {
                                    Links link = links.next();
                                    if (link.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url")) {
                                            req.setAttribute("redirectURL", link.getHref());
                                            resp.sendRedirect(link.getHref());
                                    }
                            }
                            req.setAttribute("response", Payment.getLastResponse());
                            map.put(guid, createdPayment.getId());
                    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
                            req.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
            req.setAttribute("request", Payment.getLastRequest());
            //req.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
```

}

---

In response to my first commenter below, Yozha Karlov, I have added the following:

Well, I suppose I have several reactions to that. First, thank you. Second, I think perhaps I was not clear enough about my question. I am not confused about how to retrieve the old Payment object, named 'createdPayment' above. In the full code that I copied in above, I use the exact same guid code that you reference. One problem with that is that it doesn't do anything but copy the ID of the createdPayment object into a new blank Payment object. The state of the new object is still blank, as are all its other attributes. It is a blank object with an ID and that’s it. Pretty much worthless, so I’m either missing something or the example servlet is completely wrong.

In fact, my initial method was to create a static class with a static mapping in it to map sessionIDs to HttpSession objects. I would generate a sessionID for the user's browser session and append that sessID to the cancelURL and returnURL in the redirectURLs for the payment.create() method. Then, I’d make sure that the relevant Payment object was appended to the user’s HttpSession object for later retrieval in the returnURL servlet.

```
public class SessionStore {
    public static Map<String, HttpSession> map = new HashMap<String,HttpSession>();
}

and in my main servlet, called PaymentInfoServlet2, here is the relevant code that i execute before the servlet ends and the user is re-directed to the payPal pages:

HttpSession sess=req.getSession();
String sessID=sess.getId();
SessionStore.map.put(sessID, sess);

// append sessID to redirectURLs - the URLs that the payPal pages return back to
approveURL=req.getScheme() + "://"+ req.getServerName() + ":" +req.getServerPort()+ req.getContextPath() +"/ApproveServlet?sessID=" +sess.getId();
cancelURL=req.getScheme() + "://"+ req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort()+ req.getContextPath() +"/CancelServlet?sessID=" +sess.getId();
redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(cancelURL);
redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(approveURL);
payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

// create the payment on the payPal server
Payment createdPayment = payment.create(access.getContext());

//add created Payment object to HttpSession object.
ArrayList<Payment> createdPayments=new ArrayList<Payment>();
createdPayments.add(createdPayment);
sess.setAttribute("createdPayments", createdPayments);

// redirect to payPal pages
Iterator<Links> links = createdPayment.getLinks().iterator();
while (links.hasNext()) 
{
    Links link = links.next();
    if (link.getRel().equalsIgnoreCase("approval_url")) 
    {
            url=link.getHref();
        resp.sendRedirect(url);
    }
}
```

Then, when the payPal pages returned me to my former returnURL page, I would call the following relevant code-snippets:

```
String sessID=req.getParameter("sessID");
HttpSession sess=SessionStore.map.get(sessID);
ArrayList<Payment> cPay=(ArrayList<Payment>)sess.getAttribute("createdPayments");
Payment payment=(Payment)cPay.get(0);
```

and the old payment object, with all the same attributes and everything, has been retrieved. That seems far more useful than merely copying the old payment ID into an otherwise blank Payment object. However, the old ‘createdPayment’ still has a state of ‘created’, not ‘approved’ or ‘completed’. I have no idea how move from creating an object, which I’ve outlined above, into executing the same Payment object. In fact, I don’t even understand whether payments using method=‘paypal’ are supposed to be created and executed with the same payment object. As I described in my original post, it doesn’t make sense to me that this should be so. I create a payment object, payPal sends back an approval_URL, among others, for me to redirect the user to for approval. This takes the user out of my web-application and onto the payPal server. Since payPal can’t modify my local ‘createdPayment’ variable, payPal cannot change its state. Further, it seems like I need a Payment object with a state of ‘approved’ in order to execute the payment. Therefore, I conclude that payPal must send me back a new Payment object with a lot of the same information as my ‘createdPayment’ object, but with an updated state of approved and perhaps a special token/password indicating the approved status to prevent someone from just hacking a bunch of payments into a state of approved, which would be trivially easy to do. I see that I’m getting a token, as expected, but I’m not getting a paymentID as I expected. I AM getting a payerID. Is there a way to convert the returned token and payerID into a new Payment object with a status of ‘approved’, or am I just completely missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, after redirect from PayPal site page the 'payerId' will be appenended as a request parameter, not payment id. But you'll need payment id as well to execute it. Here is code from payPal [interactive tool](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal).

```
String accessToken = "Bearer Jfdd4h4VrmvLeATBNPsGOpp7pMosTppiy.Jq6xpwQ6E";
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig);

Payment payment = new Payment("PAY-4AL22602580048540KKPBSNY");
PaymentExecution paymentExecute = new PaymentExecution();
paymentExecute.setPayerId("BKJ78SZZ8KJYY");
payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecute);
```

So the tricky part is how to preserve payment id between requests, because HTTP doesn't hold any state as we know. You can see how it implemented in example that you referred to:

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-java/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/servlet/PaymentWithPayPalServlet.java

So they generate uuid:

```
String guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
```

add the guid parameter in redirect url:

```
redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(req.getScheme() + "://"
      + req.getServerName() + ":" + req.getServerPort()
      + req.getContextPath() + "/paymentwithpaypal?guid=" + guid);
```

and associate this guid parameter with id of created payment:

```
map.put(guid, createdPayment.getId());
```

in order to use it later

```
payment.setId(map.get(req.getParameter("guid")));
```

Hope this will help

Comment: My comment was too long, so I added my response to the end of my original question to address your comment. Thanks for helping, and please see the above for my response.

Comment: In the above code where you have called the constructor for creating a payment , i get an error that it needs a Payer object as well any idea why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

According to paypal developer portal, the returned object looked like this:

```
{
    "id": "PAY-50299450TD463315FK4MDBAI",
    "intent": "sale",
    "state": "created",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
"transactions": [
{
  "amount": {
    "total": "7.00",
    "currency": "USD",
    "details": {
      "subtotal": "5.00",
      "tax": "1.00",
      "shipping": "1.00"
    }
  },
  "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
  "item_list": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Ground Coffee 40 oz",
        "price": "5.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "related_resources": []
}],
"create_time": "2016-04-21T01:44:32Z",
"links": [
{
  "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-50299450TD463315FK4MDBAI",
  "rel": "self",
  "method": "GET"
},
{
  "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-27C19584EL875221E",
  "rel": "approval_url",
  "method": "REDIRECT"
},
{
  "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-50299450TD463315FK4MDBAI/execute",
  "rel": "execute",
  "method": "POST"
}]}
```

So, you may see the field status "created". You also have the field 'created time'.

I hope it helps.